# How to add an eventhandler which can prevent any other click eventhandler with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to implement a confirmation logic for links or buttons, where I can annotate the related element with a special data-confirm attribute. If this attribute exists on the element, I would like to attach a click handler which has the power to prevent any other handler including default event, and other jQuery handlers added before or after my confirm handler was added.

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).on("click", "a[data-confirm], button[data-confirm]", function(e) {
    var confirmData = $(this).data("confirm");
    if (confirmData === "true")
      confirmData = $(this).prop("title");
    if (confirmData && !confirm(confirmData)) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

The problem is that I'm not sure about where this handler will go into the handlers list, so I guess there is a good probability that other handlers could execute before it. Also, I'm not sure if this handler will precede for example `knockoutjs'` click binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent other handlers from being called use `stopImmediatePropagation()` and to prevent default behavior use `preventDefault()`.

Like so:

```
$("body").on("click", ".elementClass[attributeName]", function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

By adding the `[attributeName]` in the selector, the selector will only apply to elements with the attribute "attributeName"

In the example above this will be executed before your `$(document)` handler as the event bubbles up the DOM and gets to the `body` before it gets to the `document`.  To ensure that this event is attached sooner, you can attach the handler to the element like so:

```
$(".elementClass[attributeName]").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The downside to this, is that this handler must be attached after the element has the attribute.

Another technique you can use with just vanilla JavaScript, however, is event capturing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture

You can do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if(event.target.hasAttribute("attributeName")){ // jQuery: if($(event.target).attr("attributeName")){...
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        //Do stuff
    }
}, true);
```

By adding `true` at the end the event is captured, meaning this will be run before other handlers.

Comment: Thanks, the first part is clear, and I know about it, however, it's not satisfactory, because I would like to prevent the lowest level handlers as well, not only those attached to document. I'm gonna check out the second part though.

Comment: My guess is that the third solution is the one that will actually work as capture happens before bubbling

Comment: Is that third code snippet browser-safe? I know about many quirks about events and their proeprties, etc.

Comment: It is for IE 9 and up, and for pretty much every version of the other browsers. So if you have to support IE8, it won't work

Comment: I'm still working on it, probably will go in another way. I'm using knockout click bindings, so it's enough for me if I inject this logic there. In any case I'll check your answer soon, and will accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If an element has more than one click handlers, the execution order of those is unspecified. So you can't reliably make one always execute first.

> Although all EventListeners on the EventTarget are guaranteed to be triggered by any event which is received by that EventTarget, no specification is made as to the order in which they will receive the event with regards to the other EventListeners on the EventTarget.

[W3C-Events-flow-basics](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic)

Comment: Yes, I know that, that's why I asked the question :)